# UIPageViewController могу ли я использовать совместно с textfield

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

возможно ли использовать в UIPageViewController совместно с text view?

или есть другой вариант решить такую проблему

**Задание**
Нужно пролистывать страницы (пальцем в лево и в право) сами страницы идут грубо говоря как карточки (в самих карточках есть информация текстовая которая очень длинная ее нужно листать) пример https://itunes.apple.com/ua/app/muzej-faktov-interesnye-fakty/id757252884?mt=8

[image]

в данном приложение перелистывание между блоками идет с помощью кнопок
меня интересует реализация через свайп в лево 
и так же возможность листать текст

наверно очень сложно задал вопрос надеюсь пример поможет понять

Comment: проще говоря у вас есть скролл вью горизонтальный с разбитием по страницам, и на каждой странице есть скролл вью вертикальный. проблема может быть только в том, что если вы повели пальцем по диагонали, система может не понять какой скролл выполнять. а в чем вопрос то?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko вот как раз этот момент я не учел  
вопрос в том какой метод лучше применить для такой задачи и проще

Comment: у вас уже есть pagecontroller, и уже есть textview (наследованный от scrollview). тут уже больше ничего не придумаешь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIPageViewController можно использовать совместно с любыми view, в том числе с textview. Это лишь вариант навигации.

Comment: а для такой задачи какой вариант посоветуете Вы?

Comment: UIPageViewController идеален для данной задачи